# AJAX - xmlhttp.responseText size?

Tags: ajax

Using the below AJAX request, what is the largest amount of HTML I can receive through this, from my ASP page? Is there no limit or performance issues? I would like to request a list of images (between 20 and 100) including the HTML code that displays them, and display it in 'myElement'.

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
else
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        document.getElementById('myElement').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
};

xmlhttp.open("GET","myPage.asp?ID="+id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no maximum limit in the HTTP spec.  Browsers or the server software might impose some sort of limit, but that limit is usually fairly high.  100 images is practically nothing, and the code for 100 images is going to be less than 1kb, unless you're doing something really wrong.